# Generating and storing unique and random numbers within a range

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, random

I tried the following code to generate random numbers and store them in a HashSet in c#:

```
class program
{
  static void Main(String[] args)
  {
    Random r=new Random();
    HashSet <int> h = new HashSet<int>();
    for (int j=0;j<9;++j)
    {
  h.Add(r.Next(9));
    }
    int [] array = h.ToArray();
    foreach(int i in array)
  Console.WriteLine(i);
    Console.ReadLine();
   }
}
```

Each time I execute the program, the number of elements being displayed differs. Since I'm using a loop to store 9 values, I expect 9 values to be displayed, which is not happening. What could be the possible error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HashSet` doesn't contain duplicates.Your loop runs `9` times but only unique numbers are added to the `HashSet`.Add your numbers directly to your array and you should see 9 numbers displaying. Or use a wider range to generate random numbers.Btw you can verify that how many numbers in the `HashSet` like this, after the `for` loop:

```
Console.WriteLine(h.Count);
```

Alternatively you can change your `for` loop like this:

```
for (int j = 0; j < 9; ++j)
{
    if(!h.Add(r.Next(9))) j--;
}
```

Comment: We could use an array, but it is displaying the numbers in an order. I want to generate numbers in random order everytime. How do I do that?

Comment: @user2195963 you can create an ordered array then shuffle it.See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273313/randomize-a-listt-in-c-sharp

Comment: Thanks, the code worked. Could you please explain the if statement you have used?